# Debugger.Launch() causes silent crash

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

Our application creates temporary appdomain, creates an in-memory assembly from a byte array, creates an instance of the type in the assembly and invokes a method on this instance. This method contains Debugger.Launch() call to force the user to attach a debugger.

[image: Debugger window image]

If I choose "no" on this window, the calling application is immediately and forcefully closed without any exception being generated whatsoever.

Is there any way to debug this and/or prevent the calling application from closing?

EDIT:

Sample code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DebuggerCrash
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var method = typeof(SampleClass).GetMethod(nameof(SampleClass.Launch), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            try
            {
                method.Invoke(null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal static class SampleClass
    {
        public static void Launch()
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
            else
            {
                Debugger.Launch();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("After launch");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is as it states, your application is throwing an exception. You could bind to appdomain and handle all exceptions, then that way you can tell it to just continue, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @Jaxi Eh? If `Debugger.Launch()` works by just throwing an exception in the application and seeing if there's anything there to catch it, it's not working [as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx): it's documented as just returning `false` if no debugger got attached.

Comment: We may need some more code to fully understand in that case, by your explaination it sounds a lot like `Debugger.Break()`

Comment: I just tested, even if I don't attach a debugger it returns True. From the documentation it states: `true if the startup is successful or if the debugger is already attached; otherwise, false.` which i sense to believe as soon as it prompts for a debugger to be attached it returns true.

Comment: There is at least one try-catch block before invoking the method containing the Debugger.Launch. The app just exists without any error anywhere.

Comment: I've added sample code to the original question.

Comment: Also, this issue occurs only on certain machines. It works just fine on my Windows 7 enterprise with VS 2010, 2015 and 2017 installed. It doesn't work, for example, on Windows server 2008 R2 enterprise with VS 2010 shell installed.